# Select field semi-functional with opaque box in top left corner

Tags: html

I am putting in a select field into a simple html file. The field is in a table, floated right in a column. For some reason, the left side of each field, under the opaque box, is the only part that's functional.

Is this because the field is floated right or something else?

```
<td><select style="max-width:20%; min-width:10%; float:right;" size="3" name="test" id="test" multiple=""> 

<option value="1">1</option> 

<option value="81">81</option> 

<option value="255">255</option> 

</select><br>

<div style="text-align:center;"><label for="test">Charge Time (ms) 
</label></div>
</td>
```

[My Observation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0x7l.jpg)

Comment: `max-width:20%` is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off the `</td>` is a stray end tag, meaning that you have put an end tag in a context that is not allowed because the tag is treated as a closing element.

Secondly, `css` would really com in handy to style this instead of doing so in the html as this is parsed as "obsolete", and it would help you solve problems like this.

Third of all, the `max-width:20%` is the problem being that it is outside the parameters of your code.